# Complex Numbers with the prey-predator equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Consider a model (very similar to Lotka-volterra prey-predator -model, exception $h$).

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = h+x(\alpha -\beta y)$$ 
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = -y(\gamma - \rho x). $$

Let's write this  in matrix form:

$$ \left(\begin{array}{c}\dot{x}  \\
\dot{y}  \end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & -\beta x  \\
\rho y & -\gamma   \end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x  \\
y  \end{array} \right)
+
\left(\begin{array}{c}
h  \\
0  \end{array} \right) 
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
0  \\
0  \end{array} \right)
$$

where the final right hand-side is due to the definition of the equilibrium. So we have a system of the form $\bar{0} = A \bar{v} + \bar{h}$. The equation $\dot{f} = A \bar{v} + \bar{h}$ is non-linear ODE, more [here](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa09/cs450/odestability.pdf), so I need to investigate the $J_{f} := \left[ \frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial y_{j}} \right]$ where $f(\bar{x}, \bar{y}) = \frac{d \bar{v_{i}}}{d t}$ (read this [link](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa09/cs450/odestability.pdf), clarifies things a lot!) So the Jacobian is needed for the stability more [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=linear%20stability%20analysis%20ode%20%2Blinearization&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDgQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ualberta.ca%2F~devries%2Fmath372-2004%2Flinearstability.pdf&ei=AEykTpmHC-Xe4QS2zY3YBA&usg=AFQjCNFZ1BeErweYpm_-5ysNcIx6VNHhvw&sig2=SseXK5RhJDoDekPir1-nhg). I am trying to solve the problem 5 [here](http://alpha.cc.tut.fi/mallinnus/kurssit/kurssit2011/MMPK/05_Piche/Harj_05.pdf).

**Clarifications needed, Some Helper Questions**

1. Fix-points? Some material mention things called "fixpoints". $F(\bar{p}) =0$ and then checking some condition, thinking -- really, no need to check it like the history?
2. linearization? Confused (see the history).

Comment: Incomprehensible. What do $z$ and $p$ have to do with the rest of the statement? What do you mean by "a situation with log(negative)"? Whatever you mean by that, how does it relate to $x\gt0,y\gt0,h\gg0$? How do you intgrate with respect to time? What is a complex equilibrium? "eigenvalues" only come up when you have a matrix, and you haven't presented one. "Negative real part"  - of what? Please think for a few minutes about what you actually want to know, and how to communicate it so that others might understand you.

Comment: @hhh: You seem to *completely* have misunderstood the question. Equilibrium means that $dx/dt=dy/dt=0$, so you should find $(x,y)$ such that the right-hand sides become zero. Then you investigate the *stability* of this equilibrium by **linearization** (and that's where the "negative real part" stuff enters), but I'm not going to explain all that here. It should be in your textbook.

Comment: Some similar lecture things [here](http://javeeh.net/lecnotes/model.pdf), some dimensionless things...cannot find the word "linearization" explained.

Comment: @HansLundmark: is there some Wikipedia entry about this "linearization"?

Comment: "Let's write this in matrix form." The matrix form you give yields $dx/dt=h-\mu x+\epsilon y^2$, which is not $dx/dt=h+x(\alpha-\beta y)$, not even close, so best rethink your matrix form. "Linearization" just means dropping the nonlinear terms; in this case, the terms with $xy$. But, really, you're going to have to read this on your own somewhere - there are dozens of textbooks that do systems of first-order ordinary differential equations - or else hire a tutor.

Comment: @hhh: I didn't find much on Wikipedia, except a very short description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Dynamical_systems), but there are lots of lecture notes and other descriptions on the internet. Search for "linearization ode" or "linear stability analysis ode", for example.

Comment: @hhh If you are going to dive into these topics more, then you have to, no you MUST!!! read [Strogatz' book](http://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Dynamics-Chaos-Applications-Nonlinearity/dp/0738204536). It is a wonderful book and shows all these steps in a progressive Strogatz way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to find the equilibrium points of this system. One possibility is $x=\frac{-h}{\alpha}, y=0$ and another one is $x=\frac{\gamma}{\rho}, y = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\rho h}{\beta\gamma}$ (plug these values in to see it for yourself).

What the idea of linearization simply stating is: Take the 1st-order Taylor series approximation of the solutions. Around some(!) neighborhood of any point in the state space, the nonlinear system $\dot x = f(x)$ behaves like a linear system $\dot x = Ax$. For this you have to use the Jacobian (first term of Taylor approx.) **evaluated at the point of linearization**. If this point moreover, is an eq. point then the constant term vanishes and you are left with a linear system, otherwise a drift term stays. Thus the overall system describes
$$
\frac{d\Delta x}{dt} = A (x_0+\Delta x)
$$
i.e. the small perturbation dynamics around the eq. point $x_0$. If $A$ is stable your system goes back to the eq. point or it goes to another eq. point or blows up.

Take the first eq. point as an example: 
$$
\left.J\right|_{eq1} = \left.\pmatrix{\alpha-\beta y &-\beta x\\ \rho y &\rho x-\gamma}\right|_{x=\frac{-h}{\alpha}, y=0}=\pmatrix{\alpha & \frac{\beta h}{\alpha}\\ 0 &-\rho\frac{h}{\alpha}-\gamma }
$$ 
Note that you have changed the sign of the variables so I can't directly tell you if this is a stable linearization, for example $\alpha = -\mu$. Check if it really is (question 3 asks this). Now you can plug in the second equilibrium point and you will get: 
$$
\left.J\right|_{eq2} = \left.\pmatrix{\alpha-\beta y &-\beta x\\ \rho y &\rho x-\gamma}\right|_{x=\frac{\gamma}{\rho}, y = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\rho h}{\beta\gamma}}=\pmatrix{\frac{-\rho h}{\gamma} &-\frac{\beta\gamma}{\rho}\\ \frac{\rho\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\rho^2 h}{\beta\gamma} &0 }
$$
The rest is simple since the eigenvalues are the solutions of 
$$
\lambda^2 + \frac{\rho h}{\gamma}\lambda + (\gamma\alpha +\rho h) = 0
$$
From this you can compute the eigenvalues and see when these variables make the discriminant negative.

Comment: hey but is it really $\rho x - \gamma$ with the Jacobian 2x2 point? Should it be $-\gamma$? Sorry I may have miscorrected your text, have to re-read...

Comment: @hhh I have fixed it now. Note that they are partial derivatives, hence $-\gamma y +\rho x y$ leads to that.

Comment: ...is it actually possible to prove the steady state by plugging the values into the formula and notice that $\dot{x}=0$ and $\dot{y} = 0$ or do I miss something if I do it that way?

Comment: That would only prove that it is an eq. point. Think of a pendulum. The upright position is also an eq. point but an unstable one. The smallest disturbance cause the solution to converge to the downward solution.

Comment: Wow this became a CW ?! I think you can shorten your question a lot if you get what needs to be done. ;)

Comment: ...and that is the reason for $J$, revealing. There must be more into this, investigating...

Comment: The question had 19 revisions by 4 users, and one or the other of those is enough to trigger the software into declaring the question CW. This provision is buried in the faq somewhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No problem, I was surprised about the number of editing. Other than that, it is fine with me.